# why do my triton not have executive file "triton" in triton/build?( I want to use the command like build/triton xxx.py xx )

Tags: linux, triton

[the figure of my linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmM32.png)

I have installed triton on kali linux.
I want to use the command like build/triton xxx.py xx ,which used pintool in xxx.py.

For example,the content of  xxx.py is :
from triton import ARCH, MemoryAccess, OPERAND
from pintool import *